# How to build HTML Table dynamically as template for sending email (ng-repeat)

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, string, angularjs-ng-repeat

Currently I build HTML templates and replace {Title} placeholder with matching values before sending 'parsed email template' to recipients but the issue is there's no way to generate 'list of data' in table dynamically, thus resorting to using angularjs 'ng-repeat' but when parsed, it sends out angularjs tags instead of generating the HTML representation

My question is how can I build 'angularjs' template with ng-repeat that can be used for sending email templates dynamically without having to load the page in browser cause it seems the angularjs page is only translated when opened in browser

How is it possible using ng-repeat to generate HTML tags dynamically, suitable enough to be sent as email message, thanks

```html
 {Title} Placeholder 

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Try to make message body in your controller and replace it with your email's message section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not directly possible with angularjs, but it's supported with angular 2+ (using nodejs on server: https://angular.io/guide/universal ).

I had an identical need and I remember attempts to achieve what you want using angularjs running on server in selenium webdriver but I couldn't find a complete and easy solution.

Instead, I copied my ng-repeat templates and converted them to very simple asp.net razor templates, and I pass my json model as *dynamic* ViewModel.
I know it's not angularjs but it's a good serverside alternative and you tagged c# too.
Example template:

```
@Model dynamic

<h4>@Model.Title</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (dynamic x in Model.Students)
  {
  <tr>
    <td>@x.FirstName</td>
    <td>@x.LastName</td>
    <td>@x.Age</td>
  </tr>
  }
</table>
```

You can use the *RazorEngine* nuget to help generate the output: http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/